# Trignometric relations

Tags: trigonometry

Given  $H = S – N$, where $S = \sin(\omega t)$ and $N = \sin(\omega t + d)$

How do I show that: $H = 2\sin(d/2)\cos(\omega t + d/2)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because that's for $N-S$.

Let $\alpha=\omega t+d/2$ and $\beta=d/2$ for avoiding denominators; then $\omega t=\alpha-\beta$ and $\omega t+d=\alpha+\beta$, so
\begin{align}
\sin(\omega t)-\sin(\omega t+d)
&=\sin(\alpha-\beta)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)\\[6px]
&=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta
 -\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta\\[6px]
&=-2\cos\alpha\sin\beta\\[6px]
&=-2\sin\frac{d}{2}\cos\Bigl(\omega t+\frac{d}{2}\Bigr)
\end{align}
which is quite different from your thesis.